# How can I retrieve a website icon?

Tags: delphi, icons, favicon

I am building a list of web Link to sites that I want to keep track of, and I would like to put the website icon, not the default browsers.

How can I do this?

Comment: Are there any service or api that i ask for a website and get the official icon of that website in return?

Answer (score 19):

A lot of sites put a favicon.ico file in the root so download the file "www.asite.com/favicon.ico" if it exists.
I think legacy IE only supports a single favicon so that should get it most of them.

You could also try and check the link tags to see if there is on located somewhere specific.

eg:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" href="http://example.com/image.ico">
```

more on favicons here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon

Answer (score 11):

Open source HTML for a page in question. There you will find a link to the icon.

For example, for this very page you can see the following:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://sstatic.net/so/favicon.ico">
<link rel="apple-itouch-icon" href="http://sstatic.net/so/apple-touch-icon.png">
```

If you mean to do it programmatically, then you need to parse HTML trying to find a link to the *.ico file in the HTML/HEAD section.

Comment: For some complement, I ask a [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66978483/how-can-i-find-a-website-icon-if-icon-element-not-showing-in-inpect-fucntion) 2 yeas ago, and didn't get a suitable answer. At these cases, companies can choose to set official icons in their IIS server, and developers can't get access to this icon by source HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Just a side note: getting the favicon is the right approach, but be forewarned that it's not as simple as it seems - see http://nick.typepad.com/blog/2008/11/favicon-hell-sm.html

Answer (score 2):

On Firefox, just add the default icon file name after a website displaying the icon, in the url. 
Ex. https://www.google.ca/favicon.ico will display googles icon. Right click and save.
Use Bookmark Favicon Changer add-on to use it in the browser. 
Works for me!

Answer (score 1):

You should look for a .ico reference in the HEAD section of the HTML. For example, looking at the google website, I found this:

http://www.google.com/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>

which is exactly the google icon.

Hope this helps :)